# Databind to a list not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I am databinding some data to a  drop down list in asp.net c#. I am getting the below error with the data being binded using the code below. Everything looks fine from my eyes, but I can figure it out. This is the weird part, the page runs fine when running it in the development environment, but when we run it in the test environment it bombs out with the error. Any suggestions?

[image]

Page Load:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (QSReturnHeaderID == Guid.Empty && !User.IsInRole("Returns_Edit") )
            Response.Redirect("ReturnsSearch.aspx");

        //Link the branch image to the branch list
        imgBranch.LinkControl = lstBranchPlant;

        //CompanyImageScript();
        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lstBranchPlant.DataBind();
            lstReasonCode.DataBind();

            if (this.QSReturnHeaderID == Guid.Empty)
            {
                sm.SetStage("HeaderEntry");

            }
            else
            {
                LoadReturnHeader();


            }                
            LoadShipToAddressNumbers();
            LoadTradingPartnerIDs();
        }
    }
```

Data Bind Code:

```
private void LoadTradingPartnerIDs()
{
    BCCR.Data.ReturnsData data = new BCCR.Data.ReturnsData();
    DataSet r = data.ReturnsTradingPartnerID_GetList();
    lstTradingPartnerID.DataSource = r;
    lstTradingPartnerID.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you post or indicate what is on line 19 of BasePage.cs?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an "*Object reference not set to an instance of an Object*" error in your `LoadTradingPartnerIDs` method.  This *always* means that you're trying to do something with an uninstantiated Object (something that has been declared but not initialized).

The stack trace you showed indicates that it's on line number 331 of ReturnsMaint.aspx.cs.  While I can't tell exactly what line that is from your code snippet, you certainly should be able to in your IDE =)

That being said, there are only a couple of possibilities in that method for what's causing the error:

1. `data.ReturnsTradingPartnerID_GetList();` is returning null, or an empty DataSet object.  This seems like the most likely culprit.  It would cause "r" to be your uninstantiated Object, and thus trying to bind it to your databound control is going to cause this error.
2. `lstTradingPartnerID` is not initialized yet (seems incredibly unlikely, since this is being called from Page_Load).

Since you're saying it works in dev, but not in test, I would make sure that you have the proper access to get data out of your data store in test.  Whatever is happening "behind the scenes" in `ReturnsTradingPartnerID_GetList();`, make sure that you're using the right connection strings etc to reach the data store that's generate your return list.  The real problem is somewhere down *that* rabbit hole.